# How to align two data sets by date in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

Given two time series with date and price (but dates don't align, ie holidays etc) how can i align the two price series against one set of dates (using vlookup?)?

```
Example:
Mar 1, 2016 | 101.52 | Mar 1, 2016 | 204.57
Mar 2, 2016 | 103.17 | Mar 3, 2016 | 207.13
Mar 3, 2016 | 102.10 | Mar 4, 2016 | 224.03
Mar 6, 2016 | 101.87 | Mar 5, 2016 | 217.15

should result in:
Mar 1, 2016 | 101.52 | Mar 1, 2016 | 204.57
Mar 2, 2016 | 103.17 | Mar 2, 2016 | 204.57
Mar 3, 2016 | 102.10 | Mar 3, 2016 | 207.13
Mar 5, 2016 | 102.10 | Mar 5, 2016 | 217.15
Mar 6, 2016 | 101.87 | Mar 6, 2016 | 217.15
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, take a deep breath and follow along...

Suppose data is in A2:D100...

- Formula for Column E: =MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$100,0)
- Formula for Column F: =MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$100,0)
- Filter col E for #N/A
- Copy dates from col C to first empty row of A
- Unfilter col E, Filter col F on #N/A
- Copy dates from col A to C
- Remove filter from sheet (no filter dropdowns)
- Sort JUST Col A+B on A
- Sort JUST Col C+D on C
- Select col B
- F5, Special, Empty cells
- OK
- type = sign, arrow up, control+enter
- Select B again
- Control+C
- Control+alt+V, choose Values.
- Repeat the part starting from "Select col B" for col D.